# Передача параметров функции

Tags: python

Добрый день!

В коде скрипта есть переменные:

```
HOST   = '127.0.0.1'
DBASE  = 'disp'
USER   = 'cpps'
PASS   = '123'
```

Как я могу передать значения переменных в процедуру ?

Такой вариант не работает

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=HOST;UID=cpps;PWD=123;DATABASE=disp")
```

Такой тоже на работает

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$HOST;UID=cpps;PWD=123;DATABASE=disp")
```

Спасибо

Comment: у меня так и реализовано

conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;UID=cpps;PWD=123;DATABASE=disp")

просто думал, что можно подставить значение переменной в строку параметров по имени

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно понял вопрос сначала - обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Исправил ещё раз :)

Answer (score 2):

Параметры передаются в строковой переменной? Тогда можно так:

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1' DBASE = 'disp' USER = 'cpps' PASS = '123'
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%(HOST)s;UID=%(USER)s;PWD=%(PASS)s;DATABASE=%(DBASE)s" % {'HOST':HOST, 'DBASE': DBASE, 'USER': USER, 'PASS': PASS})
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать конструкцию [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals):

```
HOST   = '127.0.0.1'
DBASE  = 'disp'
USER   = 'cpps'
PASS   = '123'

dsn = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%(HOST)s;UID=%(USER)s;PWD=%(PASS)s;DATABASE=%(DBASE)s" % locals()
```

Или тоже самое при помощи [`string.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec)

```
dsn = "DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={HOST};UID={USER};PWD={PASS};DATABASE={DBASE}".format(**locals())

print(dsn) # 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;UID=cpps;PWD=123;DATABASE=disp'
```